# Distinguishing errors in haskell

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads

I'm still new to Haskell. Whats the best way to distinguish between errors?
Currently I'm using the `maybe` monad but it can only 'represent one state of error'.

The following code snippet will put my question into context.

```
pulOh :: Seq          -- input X O sequence
      -> Int          -- split point real index
      -> Maybe Seq
pulOh xs n          =
  case (\(f,l)->(tlTrn f, hdTrn l)) (splSq xs n) of         -- split and process at index
    (Nothing, _)    -> Nothing                              -- first failed
    (_, Nothing)    -> Nothing                              -- last failed
    (Just f,Just l) -> Just (f ++ l)                        -- both parts passed
```

I would like the result to be able to distinguish if the call fails for `fst` or `snd`. Short-circuiting the case of both failing to `fst` fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#t:Either). It is basically the same as `Maybe` with a parameterised `Nothing` constructor, or in other words, `Maybe a` is isomorphic to `Either () a`. By replacing the `()` “unit error” with a custom error-tag type, you can make different failure cases different.

```
pulOh :: Seq -> Int -> Either String Seq
pulOh xs n = case tlTrn *** hdTrn $ splSq xs n of
    (Nothing, _)    -> Left "first failed"
    (_, Nothing)    -> Left "last failed"
    (Just f,Just l) -> Right $ f ++ l
```

(I took the liberty of replacing that lambda with a [`***`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-) “parallel pipeline”)

Comment: Thanks this works great! Is there also something similar to `fmap` that I can use for either?

Comment: @iluvAS `fmap` works on `Either a b`, affecting only the right `b` values. (There should be a more general `dimap` somewhere in the libraries but it's not widely used)

Comment: The `Either` instance for `Data.Bifunctor` provides `bimap f g (Left x) = Left (f x)` and `bimap f g (Right y) = Right (g y)`. `dimap` is from `Data.Profunctor` (which I do not understand well enough to comment on further).

Comment: @chepner there's nothing too scary about the `Profunctor` class itself – it's just like a bifunctor but _contravariant_ in the first argument, i.e. `a -> b` maps `p b c` to `p a b` instead of the other way around as you'd have with `(,)` or `Either` (these are covariant in both arguments, which is expressed by `Bifunctor`). The simplest profunctor is `->`, with `dimap h g f = g . f . h`.

Comment: Yeah, I just haven't internalized contravariant functors to the point where I can look at a problem and say "Aha!  A contravariant functor would be useful here!", which means I have even *less* intuition for when a profunctor would be useful. (I gather they are used under the hood for lenses, though?)

Comment: Yes, but I don't quite understand how they are needed for lenses (specifically, `Iso`s) either.

Comment: @chepner, whenever you have `F a b` such that `a` appears only in contravariant positions and `b` appears only in covariant positions, you have a profunctor. `Fold` from [Control.Foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.2.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html) is one such example.